# Afectar otra propiedad desde css

Tags: html, css

Tengo un componente sencillo:

```
<div class="ox-input-group">
    <!--Aqui va el icono-->
    <div class="ox-group-icon">
        <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
    </div>
    <!--Aqui va la caja de texto-->
    <input class="ox-form-control ox-input-primary">
</div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando haga hover en el input, afecte el icono?.
Intente hacer esto:

```
.ox-input-group input:hover + ox-input-group .ox-group.icon{
    color: rgba(222, 55, 46);
}
```

Pero no me funciono, alguna sugerencia??

Comment: ¿Qué le debe ocurrir al ícono?

Comment: Necesito cambiarle color

Comment: @JosuéMartínez ¿detectar el `hover` sobre el `.ox-input-group` no es una opción?

Comment: El selector `+` se aplica al siguiente elemento, en tu caso buscas afectar al anterior elemento, lamentablemente CSS3 no tiene un selector para tal caso, sin embargo Jquery si posee un método llamado `.prev()` que te podría servir. Te dejo un enlace con mas referencias. https://riptutorial.com/es/jquery/example/9900/obtener-elemento-anterior

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible puedes usar `.ox-input-group:hover` y escibes `.ox-input-group:hover > .ox-group-icon`.

La X representa tu icon.

```css
.ox-input-group {
  display: flex;
}
.ox-group-icon {
  color: red;
}
.ox-input-group:hover > .ox-group-icon {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ox-input-group">
    <!--Aqui va el icono-->
    <div class="ox-group-icon">
        <i class='bx bx-user'>X</i>
    </div>
    <!--Aqui va la caja de texto-->
    <input class="ox-form-control ox-input-primary">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

podes alternar el orden de los elementos con flexbox,  `flex-direction:column-reverse`,en tu caso serviria porque veo que el contenedor tiene 3 elementos , el segundo , siempre te va a quedar en el medio
y usar el selector de hermanos generales ~ , cual dejo documentacion abajo

```css
.ox-input-group{
   height:200px;  
    display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse
   
}


.ox-input-primary:hover ~ i{
  font-size:2rem;
  color:tomato;
  text-transform:uppercase
}
```

```html
<div class="ox-input-group">
   <input class=" ox-form-control ox-input-primary">
    
  <div  >
        <i >CAJA DE USUARIO</i>
    </div>
    <div class="ox-group-icon">
        <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
    </div>
   <i  >icono</i>
     
  
</div>
```

---

[Selector de hermanos Generales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_generales)